# Accessing a variable in another class by a another class

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

if i use static variables in C#, can it be accessed by any class? i want access a variable in class a which is have a value after executing a method, by class b can it be possible.

Comment: Smells suspiciously like a lazily-initialized singleton, which is itself a smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static` has no relationship with being able to access. 
It's the access modifiers that make it possible, For example `public`, `private`, `internal`, etc.

`static` defines how the object is supposed to be lying in the memory - single instance or multiple.

**For you answer, just making it public should do it. If you don't want to instantiate the class and your method has no dependencies on other non static resources, you can make the method static (and call the method without instantiating the class).**

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what's the access modifier for this variable. This from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

public
The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.

private
The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.

protected
The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.

internal
The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.